# Pandas: how to unpivot df correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-melt

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
  A  B  Var    Value
0 A1 B1 T1name T1
1 A2 B2 T1name T1
2 A1 B1 T2name T2
3 A2 B2 T2name T2
4 A1 B1 T1res  1
5 A2 B2 T1res  1
6 A1 B1 T2res  2
7 A2 B2 T2res  2
```

I now want to 'half' my dataframe because `Var` contains variables that should not go under the same column. My intended outcome is:

```
  A  B  Name   Value
0 A1 B1 T1     1
1 A2 B2 T1     1
2 A1 B1 T2     2
3 A2 B2 T2     2
```

What should I use to unpivot this correctly?

Comment: so you don't want  rows with Var = T1name  or T2name?

Comment: @eshirvana correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter where the string contains `res` and assign a new column with the first two characters of the var columns

```
df[df['Var'].str.contains('res')].assign(Name=df['Var'].str[:2]).drop(columns='Var')

    A   B Value Name
4  A1  B1     1   T1
5  A2  B2     1   T1
6  A1  B1     2   T2
7  A2  B2     2   T2
```

Note that this creates a slice of the original DataFrame and not a copy

Answer (score 1):

then :

```
df = df[~df['Var'].isin(['T1name','T2name'])]
```

output :

```
    A   B    Var Value
4  A1  B1  T1res     1
5  A2  B2  T1res     1
6  A1  B1  T2res     2
7  A2  B2  T2res     2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different options available looking at the df. Regex seems to be on top of the list. If regex doesn't work, maybe think of redefining your problem:

Filter `Value` by dtype, replace unwanted characters in df and rename columns. Code below

```
df[df['Value'].str.isnumeric()].replace(regex=r'res$', value='').rename(columns={'Var':'Name'})

    A   B Name Value
4  A1  B1   T1     1
5  A2  B2   T1     1
6  A1  B1   T2     2
7  A2  B2   T2     2
```